# Cloud9: rails server redirecting to OpenShift website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I have a rails app on cloud9.

I try running its server like this: `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`

It seems to work:

```
=> Call with -d to detach                                                                                                                                                                               
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                                                                                                            
[2013-04-23 22:29:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1                                                                                                                                                               
[2013-04-23 22:29:02] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-11-10) [x86_64-linux]                                                                                                                                      
[2013-04-23 22:29:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=21452 port=8080                                                                                                                              


 Cloud9  Your application is running at https://twitter.itp301.c9.io
```

But when I go to https://twitter.itp301.c9.io, it redirects to http://openshift.com

**What's going wrong?**

Comment: I am a c9 employee. We are currently working on this issue. This is due to some changes on a third party api. We will try to fix it asap. Please follow status.c9.io for updates. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem last night and am able to run it now.  Looks like its all fixed!